# History of file system GUI

Tags: gui-design

I don't know if this is the right place where to ask.

I'm doing a project about [TreeMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) for visually identifying in an intuitive manner large files on the harddisk. For that I'm looking for some history paper about **file system and navigation GUIs**: commercial and experimental.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try these links:

[A History of the GUI](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taouu/html/ch02.html)

[User Interface History](http://www.deepamehta.de/docs/history.html)

[The Graphical User Interfac](http://www.sensomatic.com/chz/gui/history.html)

[A Brief History of User Interfaces](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taouu/html/ch02.html)

Answer (score 2):

One of the earlier papers is by Douglas Engelbart, inventor of the Mouse. His initial paper 'Augmenting Human Intellect' which helped him get funding from the US military to expand his ideas is here: http://www.invisiblerevolution.net/engelbart/full_62_paper_augm_hum_int.html